# Can't identify crash cause in UIView.animate(withDuration) 'animations' closure

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a custom view that acts as a progress view, which is basically a simple set of views where I animate the leading constraints of the container that holds the value and of the view that acts as a 'filled' view, so it looks like this:

[image: Animated progress view as a gif]

This is a reusable view and is used in several places in the app. Some of the users suffer a crash that is related to the animation in the update method of this custom view, and I can't reproduce it nor I can find the issue. The method looks like this:

```swift
extension GradientProgressView {
    /// Animates the progress view to the desired % value and changes the value label
    /// - Parameter percentage: the desired % value in range [0.0 - 1.0]
    func updateProgress(percentage: Double) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
            self.labelProgress.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
        }

        // limit to 100% for correct constraint calculation
        let percentageAdapted = CGFloat(min(percentage, 1.0))

        // the available width for the value container to move left/right
        let availableValueContainerWidth = backgroundView.frame.width - labelGradientView.frame.width

        labelContainerLeadingConstraint.constant = min(availableValueContainerWidth * percentageAdapted, backgroundView.frame.width - 50)
        foregroundLeadingConstraint.constant = labelContainerLeadingConstraint.constant

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

More precisely, the crash happens in the `animation` block of the first `UIView.animate` call, which corresponds to the line 93 in the stacktrace (see below):

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
    self.labelProgress.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
}
```

Here's the stacktrace of the crash:

[image: stack trace of the crash]

I've tried using the self as a weak reference in both animation blocks, but the crash reappeared. Could someone point out to me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try putting this block of code on main thread?

Comment: What is the point of animating layoutIfNeeded ? The previous line should be more the ones to animates. Also be aware that the 2 animations may interfere as happening on the same view..

Comment: @VikasSaini animations are being performed on the main thread

Comment: @PtitXav you don't need to include the changes of constraint constants in the animation block, calling layoutIfNeeded() is sufficient, since this is just telling the autolayout that you want the layout to happen immediately and in an animated matter.. see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaDLkQxxDjM) from 3:35

Comment: What happens if you not animate the label ? BTW what if you delay the second animation after the first is fine ?

Comment: @PtitXav the thing is that I can't reproduce the crash.. but you are probably right, the second animation that calls `layoutIfNeeded()` interferes with the first one. I've just seen it now that the `transitionCrossDissolve` animation does not happen at all, you can see it in the gif

Comment: I agree with @PtitXav, I don't think that putting self.labelProgress.text = ... inside an animation block is needed. I think it will look the same if you change the text without the animation block.

Answer (score 0):

It's very tough to debug a crash that can't be reproduced, but a couple comments (that may or may not have anything to do with the crash)...

First, this block:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
        self.labelProgress.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
    }
```

doesn't really do anything, other than change the text.

If we want to **cross-dissolve** the text change in a label, we need to use `UIView.transition(...)`:

```
    UIView.transition(with: self.pctLabel, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.pctLabel.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
    })
```

Second, you *might* be running into a problem with your `availableValueContainerWidth` calculation, as you are allowing the label **width** to change based on its text. If the current value is only 1-digit, and we change it to `100%`, we might get something like this:

[image]

Giving the label a fixed width (calculate the width needed for the max value text of "100%"), it can look like this:

[image]

Of course, we could use a variable-width label and "get around" the issue by using the *center* instead of *leading* ... but the cross-dissolve and width-change animation may also look a little quirky.

Again, ***really tough*** to debug a non-reproducible crash, but those two things may be something to look at.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I've removed the first animation which includes the text change on the labelProgress, but the crash reappeared and now in the second animation block that calls self.layoutIfNeeded(). Still no clue why this happens. Maybe I should call layoutIfNeeded once before I calculate the constraints and after I set the text? I will also try giving the label a fixed width

Comment: @birkoof - *"... the crash reappeared and now in the second animation block ..."* -- well, that sounds like something else is going on not directly related to this code. Instead of randomly trying things, I would focus on creating a [mre]. We need to see what the code is doing that is initiating the presentation of this.